# How make JavaScript countdown timer based on server time?

Tags: javascript, ajax, timer

I have to make a timer that counts down to a specific time. I have already done something like this, but my timer counts down the time based on the client's time and it can be easily hacked. I know I have to do an AJAX query, but I don't know how to integrate it with my code.

I know the question is simple, I'm just learning.

```
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2020 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "  " + hours + ":"
  + minutes + ":" + seconds;

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = " Koniec czasu!";
  }
}, 1000);
```

and AJAX:

```
$(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    url: location.href,
    complete: function (req, textStatus) {
      var dateString = req.getResponseHeader('Date');
      if (dateString.indexOf('GMT') === -1) {
        dateString += ' GMT';
      }
      var date = new Date(dateString);
      $('#serverTime').text(date);
    }
  });
  var localDate = new Date();
  $('#localTime').text(localDate);
});
```

Can you help me?